# XUnit: Generalized tests

Tags: c#, xunit

I usually create a test class for each method of the SUT to test. Currently, I have the problem that I write a lot of tests that are code duplication.

1. Checking if the method throws if the object was disposed or async disposed
2. Checking if the method throws if any argument is null

There are around 6-7 tests each time to check this. In every class for every method of any SUT. Currently, I have 150+ tests to test the same thing and they keep getting more. I just want to have a base class containing all these tests and I just want to define the test data to use.

**Something like this: (does not work)**

```
public class TestBase<TSut> where TSut : IDisposable {
    protected TSut Sut { get; set; }
    protected Delegate MethodToTest { get; set; }
    protected IEnumerable<object?[]> DefaultParameters { get; set; } // Should be valid data
    protected IEnumerable<object?[]> NullCheckingParameters { get; set; } // Every set should contain valid data except for one null value

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(DefaultParameters))]
    public void TestMethod_ShouldThrowException_WhenObjectWasDisposed(object?[] data) {
        this.Sut.Dispose();
        Assert.Throws<ObjectDisposedException>(
            () => this.MethodToTest.Method.Invoke(this.Sut, data)
        );
    }
    
    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(NullCheckingParameters))]
    public void TestMethod_ShouldThrowException_WhenParameterWasNull(object?[] data) {
        this.Sut.Dispose();
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(
            () => this.MethodToTest.Method.Invoke(this.Sut, data)
        );
    }
}

public class MethodTests : TestBase<MySut> {
    public MethodTests() {
        this.Sut = new MySut();
        this.MethodToTest = this.Sut.MethodToTest;

        this.DefaultParameters = new[] {
            new object?[] {"Valid1", "Valid2", "Valid3"}
        };

        this.NullCheckingParameters = new[] {
            new object?[] {null, "Valid2", "Valid3"},
            new object?[] {"Valid1", null, "Valid3"},
            new object?[] {"Valid1", "Valid2", null}
        };
    }
}
```

The problem is that the MemberData has to be a static member. So is there a way to generalize these tests?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xUnit Non-Static MemberData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954505/xunit-non-static-memberdata)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xunit, the `InlineData`, `MemberData` and `ClassData` are all derived from the abstract class `DataAttribute` which is basically just this:

```
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Abstract attribute which represents a data source for a data theory. Data source
    //     providers derive from this attribute and implement GetData to return the data
    //     for the theory. Caution: the property is completely enumerated by .ToList() before
    //     any test is run. Hence it should return independent object sets.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    [DataDiscoverer("Xunit.Sdk.DataDiscoverer", "xunit.core")]
    public abstract class DataAttribute : Attribute
    {
        protected DataAttribute();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Marks all test cases generated by this data source as skipped.
        public virtual string Skip { get; set; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns the data to be used to test the theory.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   testMethod:
        //     The method that is being tested
        //
        // Returns:
        //     One or more sets of theory data. Each invocation of the test method is represented
        //     by a single object array.
        public abstract IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod);
    }
}
```

You can derive your own classes from this to return any sets of data you want.

For your first point, this class returns all the public methods in a class under test. It returns them as `string`'s because XUnit won't enumerate generic object types in the test explorer window. The class provides an easy way to get the method info back from the string with method `getMethodFromName`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SO74727807_xunit_generalized_tests
{
    public class GenericPublicMethodsDataAttribute : Xunit.Sdk.DataAttribute
    {
        private Type objectType;
        private MethodInfo[] methodInfos;
        private Dictionary<string, MethodInfo> index = new Dictionary<string, MethodInfo>();

        public GenericPublicMethodsDataAttribute(Type objectType_)
        {
            objectType = objectType_ ?? throw new ArgumentNullException($"Parameter {nameof(objectType_)} is null.");
            methodInfos = objectType.GetMethods();
            foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methodInfos)
            {
                string key = methodInfo.ToString();
                index.Add(key, methodInfo);
            }
        }

        public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
        {
            foreach (string key in index.Keys)
            {
                string[] methodKey = new string[] { key };
                yield return methodKey;
            }
        }

        public MethodInfo getMethodFromName(string methodName)
        {
            if (index.TryGetValue(methodName, out MethodInfo info))
            {
                return info;
            }
            throw new ArgumentException($"No method info found for method name \"{methodName}\"");
        }
    }
}
```

For your second point, for example, this class would return sets of valid data with one null value on each iteration, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SO74727807_xunit_generalized_tests
{
    public class GenericNullParameterDataAttribute : Xunit.Sdk.DataAttribute
    {
        private object[] validData;

        public GenericNullParameterDataAttribute(params object[] validData_)
        {
            validData = new object[validData_.Length];
            Array.Copy(validData_, validData, validData.Length);
        }

        public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
        {
            ParameterInfo[] parameters = testMethod.GetParameters();
            // TODO: check that the object types in the valid data match the test method parameter types.
            for (int i = 0; i < validData.Length; i++)
            {
                // Skip value types, they're not nullable
                if (!parameters[i].ParameterType.IsValueType)
                {
                    object[] methodData = new object[validData.Length];
                    Array.Copy(validData, methodData, validData.Length);
                    methodData[i] = null;
                    yield return methodData; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The method skips over value types since they are not nullable.

I discovered that it is important to make a new object array for each yield instead of trying to reuse the same one-- that confused the test discoverer.

To demonstrate, I made a small "class under test"

```
using System;

namespace SO74727807_xunit_generalized_tests
{
    class ClassUnderTest : IDisposable
    {
        private bool disposedValue;

        public void BadMethod(string param1, string param2, string param3)
        {
            // Doesn't throw on call in disposed object
            // Doesn't throw on call with null parameters
            // Doesn't do anything
        }

        public void GoodMethod(string param1, string param2, int param3)
        {
            // Throws if disposed
            if (disposedValue) throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.ToString());

            // Throws on null arguments
            if (param1 == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(param1));
            }
            if (param2 == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(param2));
            }
            // int is a non-nullable type.
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposedValue)
            {
                disposedValue = true;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(disposing: true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can write your generic unit tests like this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Xunit;

namespace SO74727807_xunit_generalized_tests
{
    public class GenericUnitTests
    {

        [Theory]
        [GenericNullParameterData("Valid1", "Valid2", 3)]
        public void GoodMethodThrowsOnNullArg(string param1, string param2, int param3)
        {
            ClassUnderTest sut = new ClassUnderTest();
            Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => sut.GoodMethod(param1, param2, param3));
        }

        [Theory]
        [GenericNullParameterData("Valid1", "Valid2", "Valid3")]
        public void BadMethodThrowsOnNullArg(string param1, string param2, string param3)
        {
            ClassUnderTest sut = new ClassUnderTest();
            Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => sut.BadMethod(param1, param2, param3));
        }

        [Theory]
        [GenericPublicMethodsData(typeof(ClassUnderTest))]
        public void PublicMethodsThrowOnDisposedObject(string methodName)
        {
            // Get a reference to the data provider attribute object
            MethodBase method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
            GenericPublicMethodsDataAttribute attr = (GenericPublicMethodsDataAttribute)method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GenericPublicMethodsDataAttribute), true)[0];
            // Now we can get the method info 
            MethodInfo methodInfo = attr.getMethodFromName(methodName);
            // Make default parameters
            ParameterInfo[] parameterInfos = methodInfo.GetParameters();
            object[] args = new object[parameterInfos.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < parameterInfos.Length; i++)
            {
                args[i] = getDefault(parameterInfos[i].ParameterType);
            }
            // Now make the object under test and dispose it
            ClassUnderTest cut = new ClassUnderTest();
            cut.Dispose();
            // Methods in disposed objects should throw
            // Note that the ObjectDisposedException will be an inner exception,
            // the actual type thrown is System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
            Assert.ThrowsAny<Exception>(() => methodInfo.Invoke(cut, args));
        }

        private static object getDefault(Type type)
        {
            if (type.IsValueType)
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            }
            return null;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void testGenericPublicMethodsDataAttribute()
        {
            var data = new GenericPublicMethodsDataAttribute(typeof(ClassUnderTest));
            Assert.NotNull(data);
        }
    }
}
```

The tests are shown in the Test Explorer like this:

[image: Test explorer display of the tests]

We can see that the good method passes them and the bad method fails.

The inherited methods like `ToString()` and `GetHashCode()` also fail--they do not throw on disposed objects. You could modify the `GenericPublicMethodsDataAttribute` class to skip the inherited methods by checking the `DeclaringType` property of the method info.